# rails multiple submit button for show and download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having follwing form

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:action => "clients_new") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'some_text' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'soem_text' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Download xls' %>
<% end %>
```

I need to form same action for both `search` and `download` in the same form how can i do it.

My controller is

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xls

def clients_new
  blahblah
  if params[:clien]=='download'
  respond_to do |format|
   format.xls
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
  end
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 2 submit buttons in the same form. The submit action would only go to one method con your controller.
What you can do, is have maybe a `radio` element to choose between search and download, then you check which option is active on your controller before do stuff.

Comment: is it possible to have multiple format for single form. Something like this 
`<%= form_tag url_for(:action => "clients_new",format: [:xls,:html]) do %>`

Comment: This information resides in the controller. It is the action you perform that renders `html` or `xls` back to the browser.

Comment: If i click search it renders html and if i click download it should render xls.

Comment: The controller should use `send_data` for `xls` and `render` to do the search. Also, read my answer again. You only have/need one button.

Comment: I added radio button as you mentioned. see my edited question. For html its working fine but i am unable to download xls

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:action => "clients_new") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'some_text' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'soem_text' %>
<%if @form_type == 'search'%>
<%=hidden_tag :form_type, "search"%>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<%else%>
    <%= submit_tag 'Download xls' %>
<%=hidden_tag :form_type, "download"%>
<%end%>
<% end %>
```

Then  in controller

```
  def clients_new
      if params[:form_type] == "search"
    #do something
    else
    end
end
```